# Build Docker container for ARM64

Tags: docker, build-pipeline, github-actions, dotnet, raspberry-pi-os

I am trying to have a Blazor app developped with .NET 7 being containerized.
It eventually targets ARM64 (Raspberry Pi).

I need to have the image created when the code is pushed to a GitHub repo.
Therefore I rely on GitHub Actions.
It creates an image to be pushed to Docker Hub.

I have prepared 2 workloads on a repo of mine.
For amd64 it works.
That said I cannot seem to make it work for arm64

I am new to building for a specific architecture.
I looked for many docs and it looks easy there but when I try myself I am running into troubles.

I am working on Docker Desktop (freshly updated to 4.16.3) on Windows 10.

These are some outputs from trials on my local machine.

> Buildx supported archs

```
D:\Users\UchiTesting\Desktop\rasp-test [master ≡ +1 ~0 -0 !]> docker buildx ls
NAME/NODE       DRIVER/ENDPOINT                STATUS  BUILDKIT PLATFORMS
mybuilder *     docker-container
  mybuilder0    npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine running v0.11.2  linux/amd64, linux/amd64/v2, linux/amd64/v3, linux/arm64, linux/riscv64, linux/ppc64le, linux/s390x, linux/386, linux/mips64le, linux/mips64, linux/arm/v7, linux/arm/v6
default         docker
  default       default                        running 20.10.22 linux/amd64, linux/arm64, linux/riscv64, linux/ppc64le, linux/s390x, linux/386, linux/arm/v7, linux/arm/v6
desktop-linux   docker
  desktop-linux desktop-linux                  running 20.10.22 linux/amd64, linux/arm64, linux/riscv64, linux/ppc64le, linux/s390x, linux/386, linux/arm/v7, linux/arm/v6
```

> Attempt at building from a ARM64 tailored Dockerfile

```
D:\Users\UchiTesting\Desktop\rasp-test [master ≡ +1 ~0 -0 !]> docker buildx build --platform arm64 --file .\Dockerfile-arm64 .
[+] Building 0.9s (4/4) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile-arm64                                                                                                                                                  0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 555B                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                           0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0                                                                                                                                     0.6s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0                                                                                                                                  0.6s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0:
------
------
 > [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0:
------
WARNING: No output specified with docker-container driver. Build result will only remain in the build cache. To push result image into registry use --push or to load image into docker use --load
Dockerfile-arm64:6
--------------------
   4 |     EXPOSE 443
   5 |
   6 | >>> FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
   7 |     WORKDIR /src
   8 |     COPY ["rasp-test.csproj", "."]
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0: no match for platform in manifest sha256:c99629b03411c7b0aa5324abd01147c8a971a8c19b6ff0b570b62d8d576b1bfa: not found
```

> Attempt at building from a default Dockerfile

```
D:\Users\UchiTesting\Desktop\rasp-test [master ≡ +1 ~0 -0 !]> docker buildx build --platform arm64 --file .\Dockerfile .
[+] Building 1.0s (4/4) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                        0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 534B                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                           0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0                                                                                                                                     0.7s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0                                                                                                                                  0.7s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0:
------
------
 > [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0:
------
WARNING: No output specified with docker-container driver. Build result will only remain in the build cache. To push result image into registry use --push or to load image into docker use --load
Dockerfile:1
--------------------
   1 | >>> FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
   2 |     WORKDIR /app
   3 |     EXPOSE 80
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0: no match for platform in manifest sha256:b017897d7702fd57ce869914c486ff5650b33c4821a343af1bf53cee3dc8fa03: not found
```

I do not understand what is happening and what to do.

Amongst others on StackOverflow it is said to be related to several reasons which solutions were to disable Docker Compose v2 or switch to Windows containers. None of that worked for me and I couldn't use `docker login` any more after I did. So I did revert to Linux containers.

For further details, check my [sandbox repo](https://github.com/UchiTesting/UT-BlazorGitHubActionsDocker).

There are Dockerfiles in the root directory.
And GitHub Actions workflows under *.github/workflows*

Many thanks

Comment: OK the problem above was because I did put the platform name wrong. It is linux/arm64 instead of arm64. That said I have other problems at the creation of the ARM64 version. In the meantime I tried to follow the docker docs about multiplatform images and didn't work until I made a custom network.
Then I ran `docker buildx create --name dotnetbuilder --driver docker-container  --bootstrap --driver-opt "network=dotnet" --use` before using buildx again.

Comment: Found the other day since .NET 7 there is a way to containerize directly from dotnet CLI.
It needs to install a NuGet package and then pass certain switches to have an ARM64 image.

`dotnet add package Microsoft.NET.Build.Containers --version 0.3.2`
`dotnet publish --os linux --arch arm64 -p:PublishProfile=DefaultContainer`
`dotnet remove package Microsoft.NET.Build.Containers`